# testing queries using rspec and factory_girl : Is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, mocking, factory-bot

I have the following classes and relationships

```
City has_many Cinemas
Cinemas has_many Movies
Movies has_many Ratings
Movies Has_many Genres through GenreMovie
```

and I want to test queries like

```
* Show me the all movies in NewYork 
* Show me the all movies in NewYork order by the rating 
* Show me the all movies in NewYork order by length_of_movie, in genre "Action" 
* show me all movies in Cinema "X" order by rating, that are in Genre "SciFi"
```

Currently the way I am doing as below, using factory girl, and chaining a bunch of models together to have data to check against,

```
city = create(:city)
cinema = create(:cinema, city: city)
5.times do 
    movie = create(:movie, cinema: cinema, tags: ["sci fi", "action"]
    3.times do 
        create(:rating, score: 2.3, movie: movie)
    end 
end
```

and repeating that 3-4 to generate enough data to query against but it seems so clunky.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

I normally test this using a very "minimalistic" approach:

e.g. for your first case I would create two movies, one in NY, and one outside. Your method should only return the one in NY

For the second, create three movies, both in NY, with different rating. Create them in a not logic way, so that, no matter what, they will be sorted. Check whether your method returns them in the right order

Similar for the other cases.

I would not just create 5x3 movies. Makes no sense, and only costs time...

Answer (score 0):

There are several factory_girl constructs you could use to clean these up. `create_list` will create an array of objects, cleaning up your `x.times do` blocks. A `with_ratings` trait on your `movie` factory could allow you to opt in to having ratings automatically created when you create a movie (via FactoryGirl callbacks). You could even have that use a transient attribute in order to control the number and rating. So your result could look something like this:

```
cinema = create(:cinema)
movies = create_list(
  :movie, 
  5, 
  :with_ratings, 
  cinema: cinema, 
  tags: [...], 
  ratings_count: 3, 
  ratings_value: 2.3
)
```

If you need access to the city, you can get it via `cinema.city`.

See:

- [transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits)
- [traits](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits)